# Regular expression for nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite

What is the correct expression for denoting this -

```
beginning/ulp-12GiwQpe/doesnotmatterwhatishere
```

I want to change this to

```
beginning/doesnotmatterwhatishere
```

for NgInx, where 12GiwQpe is any **random** string that can be generated per build

Comment: If that `12GiwQpe` is a random string of __fixed__ length containing only letters and digits (underscore counts too), it can be `/ulp-\w{6}/` (note that regex patterns containing curly braces should be enquoted inside the nginx config). The rewite rule can be `rewrite "^(.*)/ulp-\w{6}/(.*)" $1/$2 redirect;`

Comment: It should `\w{8}` instead of `\w{6}` of course.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. Can you kindly also provide a solution so that the ulp-12GiwQpe doesn't appear in the url also? 

That was great help. Kudos to you! :D

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your exact use case. The issued HTTP 302 temporary redirect (of HTTP 301 permanent redirect if the `permanent` flag would be used with the `rewrite` directive instead of `redirect` one) **will** change the URL in the browser. Omitting those flags you'll get an internal URI rewrite instead of HTTP redirect, however this way the browser URL showing at the address bar won't get changed.

Comment: Is there any way to change the browser URL?

See, the thing is, the base href is appending a unique id, I want to remove it during redirection and even from the client view. :) 

If you can help me it will be great.

Comment: The 301/302 HTTP redirect **is** the way (and the only way) to change the browser URL showed in the address bar. I'm not sure what kind of issue you are stuck with, and not sure I can help at least without being able to see the whole nginx config.

Comment: I simply want to redirect beginning/ulp-12GiwQpe/doesnotmatterwhatishere to beginning/doesnotmatterwhatishere using nginx config

Comment: That kind of redirect should happens using the rewrite rule from my very first comment. What is the web app behind the nginx? I mean, what kind of technology used to develop this app (react, angular, vue etc.)

Comment: It's angular. 

But the thing is, along with the redirect, I would also like to change the url to the redirected url in the brower. 

Can you kindly help me out in redirecting this?  @Ivan Shatsky

Comment: Still not able to find a solution @IvanShatsky

Comment: I don't know what exactly the problem you faced is, but if it is somehow related to the [angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview), that subject is out of my area of competency, sorry :(